# Office 365 SharePoint Authentication from Objective-C on IOS

Tags: authentication, claims-based-auth, sharepoint-online, apple-ios

I want to create an IOS app that connects to my Office365 SharePoint team site using the list rest services. How do I do authentication? Any examples?

Comment: Did you find the answer?

Answer (score 1):

Can't mark it as a duplicate, but this should answer your question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557040/objective-c-best-way-to-access-rest-api-on-your-iphone

Comment: Will this work for claims based authentication in Office 365?

Comment: Did you ever find out if it works with claims based auth? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no idea, sorry. Anyone else?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you need to:
1) open UIWebView and direct user to authentication page of Identity Provider (Office 365, Google, etc.);
2) get FedAuth:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    NSHTTPCookieStorage *storage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
    NSArray *cookiesArray = [storage cookies];
    for (NSHTTPCookie *cookie in cookiesArray) {
        if ([[cookie name] isEqualToString:@"FedAuth"]) {

        }
    }
}
```

3) attach this token to every request you make to SharePoint services.

```
NSURLRequest.setAllHTTPHeaderFields()
```

Comment: This works, but the problem is, from what I understand, the cookie expires after 24 hours. So it's a pain to have to login every time you want to do some work.

Comment: you also need rtFa cookie! you need to add them both with every request

Answer (score 0):

You can try OAuth authentication. Check below link which has all the steps explained in detail.

[**sharepoint-online-o365-oauth**](http://spshell.blogspot.in/2015/03/sharepoint-online-o365-oauth.html)